# Use of rel=canonical where content is distributed between 2 servers under 2 domain names

Tags: distributed-computing, canonical-link

I have a client who uses a web service for their main site and has custom coding on a shared server. The web service and the shared server have different domain names pointed at them. The client would like to have rel=canonical on all the pages on the shared server that give the SEO to the main domain name, which is on the web service site.

Is this a correct use of rel=canonical or even possible? Is there another solution?

My research findings are that rel=canonical is intended for duplicate content, not distributed content.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: cross-domain canonical are nothing unusual.

Comment: All code is written for a purpose. Often that purpose is related to system requirements or the requirements deemed important by another system. This question is not about SEO effectiveness, but about whether a piece of code is allowed by a system for a specific purpose. It also asks whether there are coding alternatives.

Comment: Before I asked my question, I did a search on whether there were other questions about rel=canonical. I believe I did my due diligence in making sure my question would be on topic.